# Inheritance of parent text decoration

Tags: html, css, inheritance

This is very simple but it just came up on me; and, I can't believe there is nothing I can do about text-decoration inheritance.

I understand that if there is a `<div>` everything in there has to be underlined. But for a nested `<div>` with a separate class or id to take on the inheritance even if (none) is selected?!? I don't buy it. This happens with text-style as well, but not color.

```css
#hello {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#me {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #cc33cc;
}
.home {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<p id="hello">hello</p>
<div id="me">me
  <div class="home">go</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is unclear what you say. Actually what is your issue?

Comment: A fiddle may help here

Comment: @mash: All the code is up there. Make your own.

Comment: "*Just tell me it isnt so*"  this type of thing is not in question title.

Comment: @BoltClock I have to politely disagree, a fiddle *would* help, it shows more interest from the OP in getting some help. Although one may create their own from the code posted above, it would be helpful and more encouraging for the OP to have created one.

Comment: @user1823: Having the best of both worlds is great, but a fiddle is not essential to a question and the lack of one shouldn't dissuade anyone from answering, particularly when the given code is simple and short enough that a fiddle isn't absolutely necessary to visualize the problem. If you think a fiddle is helpful, and the OP has already provided code, feel free to suggest an edit to the question with a link (or even a Stack Snippet as misterManSam has done), but don't put the onus on the OP to do so, especially considering the OP is a new user and may not even be aware of such a service.

Comment: `float: left;` to `.home` will help.

Answer (score 3):

You can position `.home` absolutely to prevent the text decoration from applying:

```css
#hello {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#me {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #cc33cc;
}
.home {
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<p id="hello">hello</p>
<div id="me">me
  <div class="home">go</div>
</div>
```

From the [CSS2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#lining-striking-props):

> Note that text decorations are not propagated to floating and absolutely positioned descendants, nor to the contents of atomic inline-level descendants such as inline blocks and inline tables.

You can also float it or display it as an inline-block, but doing so will place the element next to the text in the parent element rather than below it as with a block-level element. Absolutely positioning (without offsetting) will not move the element.

Since absolutely positioning an element takes it out of the flow (which is why it prevents parent text decorations from applying), this means if there are any other in-flow elements after `.home` that need to be aware of its position, you will need to style those accordingly. For example, the next element needs to have a top margin that is equal to its height, or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your styles with below CSS Code.

```
.home {  
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: You still need to remove the line as well with `text-decoration: none;`

Comment: @Krycke: `display: inline-block` will automatically remove the text decoration.

Comment: @Krycke, No need to add extra line.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I was fiddling a little to much it would seem :)

Answer (score 0):

You  should try to add Combinators in css

```
#home {
      text-decoration: underline;  
      color: #cc33cc;
      float:Right;
}


.noDecoration, #home ~ p { 
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;        
}
```

You have to write your hmtl something like this

```
<div id="home">
    <p>Home-1</p>
</div>   

<div id="home .noDecoration">
    <p>Home-2</p>
</div>
```

I hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use > * select all the elements inside #me,

```
#me > * {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #cc33cc;
}
```